# Render SVG background with Gradient

Tags: beginner, sass, svg

I'm new to and still fairly confounded by SVGs. I'm feeling pretty happy with the following hobbled together SCSS code [demonstrated here](http://codepen.io/MikeiLL/pen/mEPKYG?editors=0100):

```
//Functions to create svg backgrounds:

@function _buildSVG($bg, $width:'100%', $height:'100%', $viewboxx:'0', $viewboxy:'0', $viewboxw:'274', $viewboxh:'510') {
  $bg: '%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20viewBox%3D%22#{$viewboxx}%20#{$viewboxy}%20#{$viewboxw}%20#{$viewboxh}%22%20width%3D%22#{$width}%22%20height%3D%22#{$height}%22%3E%23#{$bg}%3C%2Fsvg%3E';
  @return $bg;
}

@function _buildPath($path, $parameters) {
  $icon: '%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22#{map-get($parameters, color)}%22%20stroke%3D%22#{map-get($parameters, stroke-color)}%22%20stroke-width%3D%22#{map-get($parameters, stroke-width)}%22%20style%3D%22#{map-get($parameters, css)}%22%20d%3D%22#{$path}%22%20%2F%3E';
  @return $icon;
}

@function renderSVG(
  $backgroundName,
  $color,
  $stroke-color: white,
  $stroke-width: 2px,
  $width: '100%',
  $height: '100%',
  $viewboxx: 0,
  $viewboxy: 0,
  $viewboxw: 274,
  $viewboxh: 510,
  $css: '' // arbitrary css
  ){
    $parameters: (
      'color': $color,
      'stroke-color': $stroke-color,
      'stroke-width': $stroke-width,
      'css': $css
    );

    $backgrounds: (
      bishop: _buildPath('M142.875,133.254c-2.445,0.459 -9.707,1.823 -11.649,2.187c-4.049,0.795 -4.049,0.795 -4.968,-3.423c-4.487,-23.915 -12.495,-66.626 -15.751,-83.996c-0.718,-3.829 -0.718,-3.829 -5.285,0.011c-15.435,13.555 -31.879,34.306 -31.879,63.278c0,21.094 4.218,42.188 16.875,67.5c0,0 -8.438,0 -8.438,4.219c0,4.219 8.438,4.219 8.438,4.219c0,0 0,12.656 -4.219,16.875c0,0 -12.656,0 -12.656,8.437c0,8.438 12.656,8.438 12.656,8.438c-12.656,0 -25.313,0 -25.313,12.656c0,12.656 12.657,12.656 25.313,12.656c8.437,16.875 8.437,101.25 -12.656,147.657c-4.219,4.218 -12.657,4.218 -12.657,4.218c0,37.969 -54.843,46.407 -54.843,71.719c0,12.656 21.093,21.094 21.093,21.094c0,0 -25.312,4.219 -25.312,8.437l0,4.219c0,4.219 0,4.219 4.219,4.219l261.562,0c4.219,0 4.219,0 4.219,-4.219l0,-4.219c0,-4.218 -25.313,-8.437 -25.313,-8.437c0,0 21.094,-8.438 21.094,-21.094c0,-25.312 -54.844,-33.75 -54.844,-71.719c0,0 -8.437,0 -12.656,-4.218c-21.094,-46.407 -21.094,-130.782 -12.656,-147.657c12.656,0 25.312,0 25.312,-12.656c0,-12.656 -12.656,-12.656 -25.312,-12.656c0,0 12.656,0 12.656,-8.438c0,-8.437 -12.656,-8.437 -12.656,-8.437c-4.219,-4.219 -4.219,-16.875 -4.219,-16.875c0,0 8.438,0 8.438,-4.219c0,-4.219 -8.438,-4.219 -8.438,-4.219c12.656,-25.312 16.875,-46.406 16.875,-67.5c0,-46.406 -42.187,-71.718 -54.844,-80.156c12.657,-16.875 4.219,-29.531 -8.437,-29.531c-12.656,0 -21.094,12.656 -8.438,29.531c2.022,10.786 13.758,73.382 18.226,97.212c0.701,4.066 0.701,4.066 -3.537,4.887l0,0Z', $parameters),
      star: _buildPath('M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z', $parameters)
    );

    $background: _buildSVG(map-get($backgrounds, $backgroundName),
                            $width,
                            $height,
                            $viewboxx,
                            $viewboxy,
                            $viewboxw,
                            $viewboxh);
    @return url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,#{$background}");
  }

// ----
// Sass (v3.4.7)
// Compass (v1.0.1)
// ----

/// Convert angle
/// @author Chris Eppstein
/// @param {Number} $value - Value to convert
/// @param {String} $unit - Unit to convert to
/// @return {Number} Converted angle
@function convert-angle($value, $unit) {
  $convertable-units: deg grad turn rad;
  $conversion-factors: 1 (10grad/9deg) (1turn/360deg) (3.1415926rad/180deg);
  @if index($convertable-units, unit($value)) and index($convertable-units, $unit) {
    @return $value
             / nth($conversion-factors, index($convertable-units, unit($value)))
             * nth($conversion-factors, index($convertable-units, $unit));
  }

  @warn "Cannot convert `#{unit($value)}` to `#{$unit}`.";
}

/// Test if `$value` is an angle
/// @param {*} $value - Value to test
/// @return {Bool}
@function is-direction($value) {
  $is-direction: index((to top, to top right, to right top, to right, to bottom right, to right bottom, to bottom, to bottom left, to left bottom, to left, to left top, to top left), $value);
  $is-angle: type-of($value) == 'number' and index('deg' 'grad' 'turn' 'rad', unit($value));

  @return $is-direction or $is-angle;
}

/// Convert a direction to legacy syntax
/// @param {Keyword | Angle} $value - Value to convert
/// @require {function} is-direction
/// @require {function} convert-angle
@function legacy-direction($value) {
  @if is-direction($value) == false {
    @warn "Cannot convert `#{$value}` to legacy syntax because it doesn't seem to be an angle or a direction";
  }

  $conversion-map: (
    to top          : bottom,
    to top right    : bottom left,
    to right top    : left bottom,
    to right        : left,
    to bottom right : top left,
    to right bottom : left top,
    to bottom       : top,
    to bottom left  : top right,
    to left bottom  : right top,
    to left         : right,
    to left top     : right bottom,
    to top left     : bottom right
  );

  @if map-has-key($conversion-map, $value) {
    @return map-get($conversion-map, $value);
  }

  @return 90deg - convert-angle($value, 'deg');
}

/// Mixin printing a linear-gradient
/// as well as a plain color fallback
/// and the `-webkit-` prefixed declaration
/// @access public
/// @param {String | List | Angle} $direction - Linear gradient direction
/// @param {Arglist} $color-stops - List of color-stops composing the gradient
@mixin linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops...) {
  @if is-direction($direction) == false {
    $color-stops: ($direction, $color-stops);
    $direction: 180deg;
  }

  background: nth(nth($color-stops, 1), 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(legacy-direction($direction), $color-stops);
  background: linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops);
}

@mixin linear-gradient-svg(
  $shape,
  $color,
  $stroke-color: transparent,
  $stroke-width: 0,
  $repeat-scroll-placement-size: no-repeat scroll 100% / 100% auto,
  $width: 100%,
  $height: 100%,
  $viewboxx: 0,
  $viewboxy: 0,
  $viewboxw: 274,
  $viewboxh: 510,
  $css: '',
  $direction: 180deg,
  $color-stops...) {
  @if is-direction($direction) == false {
    $color-stops: ($direction, $color-stops);
    $direction: 180deg;
  }

  background: renderSVG($shape, $color) $repeat-scroll-placement-size, nth(nth($color-stops, 1), 1);
  background: renderSVG($shape, $color) $repeat-scroll-placement-size, -webkit-linear-gradient(legacy-direction($direction), $color-stops);
  background: renderSVG($shape, $color) $repeat-scroll-placement-size, linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops);
}

// Test

.wrap {
  @include linear-gradient-svg(bishop, none, black, 2, no-repeat scroll 10px 100% / 10% auto, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 42deg, #B58234 0%, #D2B545 50%, #D7C04D 50.01%, #FFFFFF 100%);
}
```

Did I mention that I'm also still getting my feet wet with SCSS? The thing that bothers me the most about the above @mixin are the dozen parameters that need to be supplied in order that the final parameters can be recognized.

From what I understand, the ugly (to me, anyway) `urlEncoded` strings are necessary for compatibility with IE (of course).

Maybe it would be better to just send the `viewbox` parameters as a single string and `urlEncode` it within SCSS. Aside from a [gulp, npm plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-urlencode-inline-svgs), I'm not seeing a native way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Well one improvement, aside from adding some `///Documenation` is that using the following little function:

```
///Functions to create svg backgrounds:

/// Replace `$search` with `$replace` in `$string`
/// @author Hugo Giraudel
/// @param {String} $string - Initial string
/// @param {String} $search - Substring to replace
/// @param {String} $replace ('') - New value
/// @return {String} - Updated string
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);

  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }

  @return $string;
}

/// Create a urlEncoded SVG DOM element
/// @author Mike iLL
/// @param {String} $bg - SVG PATH, including parameters
/// @param {String} $width - Width of SVG DOM Element
/// @param {String} $height - Height of SVG DOM Element
/// @param {String} $viewbox - Four values, separated by spaces, compatible with svg viewbox specifications
/// @return {String} urlEncoded SVG DOM Object
@function _buildSVG($bg, $width:'100%', $height:'100%', $viewbox:'0 0 100 100') {
  $width: str-replace($width, '%', '%25');
  $height: str-replace($height, '%', '%25');
  $viewbox: str-replace($viewbox, ' ', '%20');
  $bg: '%3Csvg%20width%3D%22#{$width}%22%20height%3D%22#{$width}%22%20viewBox%3D%22#{$viewbox}%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E#{$bg}%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A%0A';
  @return $bg;
}
```

I can send the `viewbox` values as a single parameter.

```
.wrap {
  @include linear-gradient-svg(bishop, none, white, 2, no-repeat scroll 10px 100% / 10% auto, '100%', '100%', '0 0 274 510', '', 42deg, #B58234 0%, #D2B545 50%, #D7C04D 50.01%, #FFFFFF 100%);
}
```

Apparently there are also Sass libraries out there (of course!) that provide various mixins, functions, etc. [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io) looks pretty interesting.